# how to scroll focus a particular div having same class name or same attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to scroll focus a particular div having same class name or same attribute, when click on li have class name list1 then the scroll need to focus on div class list1

```
<ul>
<li class="list1">list1</li>
<li class="list2">list1</li>
<li class="list3">list1</li>
</ul>
<div class="list1"></div>
<div class="list2"></div>
<div class="list3"></div>
```

Comment: Please write what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can try this solution.

```
<ul>
<li class="list1"><a href="#list1">list1</a></li>
<li class="list2"><a href="#list2">list2</a></li>
<li class="list3"><a href="#list3">list3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="list1">list1</div>
<div id="list2">list2</div>
<div id="list3">list3</div>
```

Comment: @ Makwana Ketan  no friend  iam tring with jquery

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution. it will definitely help you.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){      
jQuery('ul li').click(function(){
        var myClass = jQuery(this).attr("class");
        jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: jQuery('div.'+myClass).offset().top }, 1000);         
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<ul>
  <li class="list1">list1</li>
  <li class="list2">list2</li>
  <li class="list3">list3</li>
</ul>
<div class="list1">list1</div>
<div class="list2">list2</div>
<div class="list3">list3</div>
```

Comment: some issue there second click it refocus the li

Comment: Its working fine at my end. Add big contents in **div** then you can analyse better. thanx

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                $(".menu li").click(function () {
                    var activeLink = $(this).attr('class');
                    var activeElementPosition = $('div.' + activeLink).position();
                    $('body').animate({
                        scrollTop: activeElementPosition.top
                    }, 300);
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
                <li class="list1">list1</li>
                <li class="list2">list2</li>
                <li class="list3">list3</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="list1"></div>
            <div class="list2"></div>
            <div class="list3"></div>
```

Comment: at the end of scroll ,refocus div is not working perfectly

Comment: that means on clicking 'li.list3', 'div.list3' is not scrolling to the top of view port?